# How many parallelograms can be found in a equilateral triangle divided into equal equilateral triangles?

Tags: combinatorics

How many parallelograms can be found in a equilateral triangle of length 10 units divided equally into equilateral triangle of length 1 unit?

Can anyone come up with a detailed solution?

Comment: I find necklace problems the hardest to solve...don't know what that implies about olympiads.

Comment: Can I have an example?

Comment: I've found the famous 'Hat Check Problem' to be quite very difficult. Here are a couple of examples asked on this forum: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/876126/131263 and http://math.stackexchange.com/q/627913/131263. In addition to that, Integer Partitioning questions can also be very difficult (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_%28number_theory%29).

Comment: @user168802 : How many necklaces can be formed by using 3 white pearls, 4 red pearls, and 5 green pearls? Studying under Noga Alon made me quite efficient at solving problems like these :)

Comment: Thanks you so much! Oria Gruber, Barak Manos.

Comment: Integer Partitioning is quite interesting!

Comment: Okay, how about this one for a bit? How many ways can you mark 8 squares of an 8 by 8 chessboard so that no two marked squares are in the same row or column, and none of the four corner squares is marked? (Rotations and reflections are considered different)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extend the triangle down one more row. Then extend the sides of the parallelogram until they hit that row, and mark those spots they hit.

The bijection should now be clear.